# Why can't I validate an embedded document in mongoose? What is the right way to do this?

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

I have an schema like this:

```
var testSchema = new Schema({
        foo: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
        bar: {
            fooBar: { type: String },
            barFoo: { type: String }
        }
});
```

And I must validate values of `bar` based on `foo` values, something like this:

```
testSchema.path("bar").validate(function(bar){
    if(this.foo === "someValue")
        //return custom validation logic 1
    else if(this.foo === "anotherString")
        //return custom validation logic 2  
    else
        return false;
});
```

But when I try to strat my app I get the following error:

```
/Users/Renato/github/local/prv/domain/models/testModel.js:34
testSchema.path("bar").validate(function(bar){
                       ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'validate' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here? Whats the correct way to validate this object??? I googled for it but I could not seem to find anything out! Even updated my mongoose version to `~3.5.5`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mongoose [doesn't appear to consider](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/3.5.5/lib/schema.js#L175-L207) `'bar'` to be a `path` itself, but rather just a `prefix` for 2 separate paths -- `'bar.fooBar'` and `'bar.barFoo'`:

```
testSchema.path("bar.fooBar").validate(function(fooBar){
    if(this.foo === "someValue")
        //return custom validation logic 1
    else
        return false;
});

testSchema.path("bar.barFoo").validate(function(barFoo){
    if(this.foo === "anotherString")
        //return custom validation logic 2
    else
        return false;
});
```

You may also find [`schema.pre()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre) to be useful for validating the model collectively (another example can be found in the [Sub Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) documentation):

```
testSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if(this.foo === "someValue")
        return next(new Error('Invalid 1'));
    else if(this.foo === "anotherString")
        return next(new Error('Invalid 2'));
    else
        next();
});
```

Comment: I have the same issue with creating and updating, if I do `testModel.create({ foo: { foobar: 'foo' } } )` it doesnt work, any workaround? @jonathan-lonowski